# How to use base 64 data with android?

Tags: android, encoding, base64

I try to debug an android application but I need help to decode data.

The Webview of the application do an http request and receive base64 data.

How can I decode data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Base64 encoded data. You can decode it with the `atob` function. Assuming `encodedData` holds the Base64 encoded data:

```
var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData);
```

`atob` is supported by all major browsers;

Answer (score 3):

assuming you already get the `data` as `string` or `byte[]` type,

```
Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

you can compare the output of the decoding with http://www.base64decode.org

if you want to decode this in WebView using JS, then infused's answer works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thx, I'm a newbie here, and have modified the answer as you suggested.

Comment: @xudshen, you don't need an external base64 library. Base64 support is built into all modern browsers via the `atob` and `btoa` functions.

Comment: @infused I'm not sure whether he wants to debug in the Android application(using Java) or in the WebView(as you said, the modern browser, using JavaScript).